# Invoke-Sqlcmd : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

My PowerShell script keeps failing when trying to import a CSV file.

The error message reads: "Invoke-Sqlcmd : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

In my CSV file, I have a column called "LastWriteTime"

Here is my PowerShell script

```
$database = 'test'
$server = 'leasesql'
$table = 'dbo.ssis'

Import-CSV C:\temp\text.csv | ForEach-Object {
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "INSERT INTO $table (PSComputerName, FullName, Extension, LastWriteTime)
 VALUES ('$_.PSComputerName','$_.FullName','$_.Extension','$_.LastWriteTime,')"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find out that I need to put the columns in $($_.colmunname)

Import-CSV C:\temp\ssis.csv | ForEach-Object {
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "INSERT INTO $table VALUES ('$($*.PSComputerName)','$($*.FullName)','$($*.Extension)','$($*.LastWriteTime)')"